# How is pandas groupby method actually working?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I was trying to understand pandas.dataFrame.groupby() function and I came across this example on the documentation:

```
    In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
   ...:                           'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
   ...:                    'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
   ...:                           'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
   ...:                    'C' : np.random.randn(8),
   ...:                    'D' : np.random.randn(8)})
   ...: 

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
     A      B         C         D
0  foo    one  0.469112 -0.861849
1  bar    one -0.282863 -2.104569
2  foo    two -1.509059 -0.494929
3  bar  three -1.135632  1.071804
4  foo    two  1.212112  0.721555
5  bar    two -0.173215 -0.706771
6  foo    one  0.119209 -1.039575
7  foo  three -1.044236  0.271860
```

Not to further explore I did this:

```
print(df.groupby('B').head())
```

it outputs the same dataFrame but when I do this:

```
print(df.groupby('B'))
```

it gives me this:

```
<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7f65a585b390>
```

What does this mean? In a normal dataFrame printing `.head()` simply outputs the first 5 rows what's happening here?

And also why does printing `.head()` gives the same output as the dataframe? Shouldn't it be grouped by the elements of the column `'B'`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you use just

```
df.groupby('A')
```

You get a [`GroupBy` object](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/core/groupby.py#L1632-L1657).  You haven't applied any function to it at that point.  Under the hood, while this definition might not be perfect, you can think of a `groupby` object as:

- An iterator of *(group, DataFrame)* pairs, for DataFrames, or
- An iterator of *(group, Series)* pairs, for Series.

To illustrate:

```
df = DataFrame({'A' : [1, 1, 2, 2], 'B' : [1, 2, 3, 4]})
grouped = df.groupby('A')

# each `i` is a tuple of (group, DataFrame)
# so your output here will be a little messy
for i in grouped:
    print(i)
(1,    A  B
0  1  1
1  1  2)
(2,    A  B
2  2  3
3  2  4)

# this version uses multiple counters
# in a single loop.  each `group` is a group, each
# `df` is its corresponding DataFrame
for group, df in grouped:
    print('group of A:', group, '\n')
    print(df, '\n')
group of A: 1 

   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  2 

group of A: 2 

   A  B
2  2  3
3  2  4 

# and if you just wanted to visualize the groups,
# your second counter is a "throwaway"
for group, _ in grouped:
    print('group of A:', group, '\n')
group of A: 1 

group of A: 2
```

Now as for `.head`.  Just have a look at the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) for that method:

> Essentially equivalent to `.apply(lambda x: x.head(n))`

So here you're actually applying a function to each group of the groupby object.  Keep in mind `.head(5)` is *applied* to each group (each DataFrame), so because you have less than or equal to 5 rows per group, you get your original DataFrame.

Consider this with the example above.  If you use `.head(1)`, you get only the first 1 row of each group:

```
print(df.groupby('A').head(1))
   A  B
0  1  1
2  2  3
```