# From ndarray to iterable lists/variables

Tags: python, pandas, multidimensional-array

I have the following array which is a list of samples, probes, values for the probe, a boolean to describe if its a control (not all controls will contain the word "control") and a molecular weight for the probe. The array is the result of importing using pandas and merging a template and sample import list. The example array:

```
array([('Sample1', 'Control1',  846,  True, 130),
       ('Sample1', 'Control2',  527,  True, 202),
       ('Sample1', 'Control3',  493,  True, 274),
       ('Sample1', 'Control4',  426,  True, 418),
       ('Sample1', 'Control4',  191,  True, 490),
       ('Sample1', 'Probe1', 1647, False, 138),
       ('Sample1', 'Probe2', 1146, False, 170),
       ('Sample1', 'Probe3',  958, False, 210),
       ('Sample1', 'Probe4',  814, False, 242),
       ('Sample1', 'Probe5',  301, False, 282),
       ('Sample2', 'Control1', 1355,  True, 130),
       ('Sample2', 'Control2',  785,  True, 202),
       ('Sample2', 'Control3',  936,  True, 274),
       ('Sample2', 'Control4',  748,  True, 418),
       ('Sample2', 'Control4',  335,  True, 490),
       ('Sample2', 'Probe1', 2532, False, 138),
       ('Sample2', 'Probe2', 1679, False, 170),
       ('Sample2', 'Probe3', 1488, False, 210),
       ('Sample2', 'Probe4', 1387, False, 242),
       ('Sample2', 'Probe5',  500, False, 282),
       ('Sample3', 'Control1', 1701,  True, 130),
       ('Sample3', 'Control2',  936,  True, 202),
       ('Sample3', 'Control3', 1048,  True, 274),
       ('Sample3', 'Control4',  705,  True, 418),
       ('Sample3', 'Control4',  308,  True, 490),
       ('Sample3', 'Probe1', 2957, False, 138),
       ('Sample3', 'Probe2', 1994, False, 170),
       ('Sample3', 'Probe3', 1663, False, 210),
       ('Sample3', 'Probe4', 1300, False, 242),
       ('Sample3', 'Probe5',  545, False, 282)],
      dtype=[('FILENAME', 'O'), ('Probe', 'O'), ('Value', '<i8'), ('QC', '?'), ('MW', '<i8')])
```

Everything is together at the moment. Whenever I try to iterate through the array according to the probe or the boolean I get results that include all of the samples.

I would like to produce seperated iterable lists saved in a variable for each sample so for example: I can take sample 1, work out the sum of the probe values for those that are marked as true, store it in a variable and do something with that number later. What would be the best way to do this?

Thank you in advance

**Adding some more information:**

Ideally I want to be able to take any sample, and for each probe in that sample be able to return a value for that sample alone.

I want to be able to take the probes value and divide it by the sum of the True probes to create a ratio for each probe of each sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to produce seperated iterable lists saved in a variable
>   for each sample so for example: I can take sample 1, work out the sum
>   of the probe values for those that are marked as true, store it in a
>   variable and do something with that number later. What would be the
>   best way to do this?

A suggestion: rather than creating a ton of new variables one-by-one, a more scalable approach is to enclose the results inside some type of data structure.

Since you're already using Pandas, as you indicate, you may want to consider Pandas `groupby` functionality here.  An example that groups on `FILENAME` and takes the sum of `Value` where `QC` is True:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> data = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> data[data.QC==1].groupby('FILENAME')['Value'].sum()
FILENAME
Sample1    2483
Sample2    4159
Sample3    4698
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

Now, if you'd really like to assign separate variables, you could unpack these results with something like:

```
>>> s1, s2, s3 = data[data.QC==1].groupby('FILENAME')['Value'].sum()

>>> s1
2483

>>> s2
4159

>>> s3
4698

>>> s1, s2, s3
(2483, 4159, 4698)
```

To normalize all of the probes against the sum of the control probes:

```
>>> sums = data[data.QC==1].groupby('FILENAME', as_index=False)['Value'].sum()
>>> merged = data[data.QC==0].merge(sums, on='FILENAME', suffixes=('', '_sum'))
>>> merged['prop'] = merged['Value'] / merged['Value_sum']
>>> merged
   FILENAME   Probe  Value     QC   MW  Value_sum    prop
0   Sample1  Probe1   1647  False  138       2483  0.6633
1   Sample1  Probe2   1146  False  170       2483  0.4615
2   Sample1  Probe3    958  False  210       2483  0.3858
3   Sample1  Probe4    814  False  242       2483  0.3278
4   Sample1  Probe5    301  False  282       2483  0.1212
5   Sample2  Probe1   2532  False  138       4159  0.6088
6   Sample2  Probe2   1679  False  170       4159  0.4037
7   Sample2  Probe3   1488  False  210       4159  0.3578
8   Sample2  Probe4   1387  False  242       4159  0.3335
9   Sample2  Probe5    500  False  282       4159  0.1202
10  Sample3  Probe1   2957  False  138       4698  0.6294
11  Sample3  Probe2   1994  False  170       4698  0.4244
12  Sample3  Probe3   1663  False  210       4698  0.3540
13  Sample3  Probe4   1300  False  242       4698  0.2767
14  Sample3  Probe5    545  False  282       4698  0.1160
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Would this also allow me to iterate over the values individually for each sample that I've grouped? 

In terms of the bigger picture I need to work out the sum of the True probes which I can do using your method, then I need to get the value for each probe in each sample, divide these by the sum of the True probes and return the value.

Comment: Yes; it's a pretty flexible tool.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45255236/how-is-pandas-groupby-method-actually-working/45255322#45255322) for some explanation.

Comment: When you say "get the value for each probe in each sample," do you mean only Probe1, Probe2, ..., or also the Control1, Control2 samples?

Comment: I would need the value for all of the probes. I'm basically trying to normalise all of the probes against the sum of the control probes.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. I'm looking for a way to take this data out of the array to use for various other things so while your answer is great and does technically answer my question I think I am asking a bit much without knowing as much as I should. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Without pandas:

You have an array of tuples.
A tuple in python is e.g. `mytuple = (1, 3, 1)`

To access elements from a tuple use:

```
mytuple[0] # for the first element
```

For literate over a list try:

```
tupleList =[(1,3,1), (2,6,2)]
for el in tupleList:
    print(el[0]) # prints first element of all tuples in list
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer and time. I know how to get values out of the lists but my problem is I do not know how to seperate the samples out and get the information individually. Ideally I need to be able to do this generically in a function of some sort.